# Fetch particular data from nested json using MVC in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I know to work out  simple concepts using backbone.js.below is my nested json file

```
    {
        "Re":
        {
            "Si":
            [
                {
                    "Def":
                    {
                        "StName": "Gau00",
                        "SID": "1",
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ParentID": "",
                        "Ty": "GAU",
                        "TypID": "2"
                    },
                    "Entities":
                    [
                        {
                            "EntityId": "2003",
                            "Index": "1",
                            "Value": "00"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntityId": "2006",
                            "Index": "1",
                            "Value": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntityId": "2004",
                            "Index": "1",
                            "Value": "B"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntityId": "5",
                            "Index": "1",
                            "Value": "54"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntityId": "9007",
                            "Index": "1",
                            "Value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "EntityId": "9703",
                            "Index": "1",
                            "Value": "0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Connections":
                    [
                        {
                            "SourceID": "2",
                            "DestinationID": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Def":
                    {
                        "StName": "Tan",
                        "ID": "2",
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ParentID": "",
                        "Ty": "TA",
                        "TypID": "3"
                    },
                    "Entities": "",
                    "Connections":
                    [
                        {
                            "SourceElementID": "5",
                            "DestinationID": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "SourceID": "2",
                            "DestinationID": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
        ]
     }  
   }
```

Now with the StName i have to get all the other details from this nested json using backbone.js.Can anyone help me with ideas.

Comment: i have access all details with the stName wen i click stName i shd get al other details tat can be viewed in a template

Answer (score 0):

First convert JSON string to Javascript Object then use the following algorithm:

```
for each element in "Si":
   if element["Def"]:
       if element["Def"]["StName"] == "YOUR REQUIRED VALUE":
          return element["Def"]
```

Write a function that takes your object, and iterate through the object and check StName with your required value. If condition true, return the current object.

Comment: how this cud be incorporated using backbone.js

Comment: how the algorithm be brought inside backbone.js

Comment: i know to implement it in a usual program.In backbone.js we MVC framework so where to bring in this logic is my doubt.moreover i wan the result to be viewed in the template

Comment: You could attach a function to your Model class

Comment: ya i cud..thanks for ur suggestion..is it possible to bring in the entire json file inside var model = backbone.model.extend({var data = {json data},function()});is dis correct?

Comment: instead, you could convert a JSON string to Js object and send that to your modal. that would be better

Comment: i tried but its not working...can u jus provide a example just with the outline?